# Spring MVC custom Class property editor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

What's wrong in this code?

I have a  bound to a class "Fornitore fornitore" property this way:

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {       

        binder.registerCustomEditor(Fornitore.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {          
            @Override
            public void setAsText(String fornitoreId) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                logger.info("FORNITORE:: setValue");
                setValue((Fornitore) fornitoreService.getFornitore(fornitoreId));
            }
            @Override
            public String getAsText() {
                logger.info("FORNITORE:: getValue");
                if (getValue() == null) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    return ((Fornitore) getValue()).getRagioneSociale();
                }               
            }           
        });
    }
```

Ends up with:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at it.trew.prove.model.beans.Fornitore_$$_javassist_0.getRagioneSociale(Fornitore_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at it.trew.prove.web.controllers.ScadenziarioController$1.getAsText(ScadenziarioController.java:56)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see any relation between the spring DataBinder above and the Hibernate Session error below.  I see nothing obviously wrong with the data binder, but it doesn't have anything to do with starting a hibernate session.

Comment: you got reason man... but... I wanted to know if I understand the propertyeditor-form-binding mechanism for custom pojos. is it correct?

Comment: Seems like it, though I've not had to utilize \@InitBinder much.  If you're using Spring 3.1, you may want to take a look at RequestMappingHandlerAdapter which allows you to configure additional parameter types and how to populate them for any \@RequestMapping-handled methods.

Comment: Heh, it seems I have no idea how to output a literal '@' without this thinking I'm attempting to notify a user.  \ isn't pretty, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems old, but I've been cracking my head the entire day and hope my solution will help somebody.

It seems that the method

```
fornitoreService.getFornitore(fornitoreId)
```

is returning a proxy object and not a real object. I don't know how the repository is implemented, but my guess that the underlying repository method below the service is returning a proxy object and not a real one.

In my case (Spring Data), the solution was changing the underlying repository method from JpaRepository getOne to CrudRepository findOne method.